# Specific Normalization and denormalization context not working in Symfony 5 Api-Platform

Tags: php, annotations, api-platform.com, symfony5

I am following [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course/symfony-api-platform-reactjs-full-stack-masterclass/) by Piotr Jura.

I have a User Entity like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={"groups"={"GET"}},
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "GET"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')",
 *              "normalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"GET"}
 *              }
 *          },
 *          "PUT"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') and object === user",
 *              "denormalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"PUT"}
 *              }
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "POST"={
 *              "denormalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"POST"}
 *              }
 *          }
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"GET"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=6, max=255)
     * @Groups({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *      pattern="/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/",
     *      message="Passwords must be at least 7 characters long and contain at least one digit, one uppercaseletter, and one lowercase letter" 
     * )
     * @Groups({"PUT", "POST"})
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=6, max=255)
     * @Groups({"GET", "POST", "PUT"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @Assert\Length(min=6, max=255)
     * @Groups({"POST", "PUT"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\BlogPost", mappedBy="author")
     * @Groups({"GET"})
     */
    private $posts;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="author")
     * @Groups({"GET"})
     */
    private $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getPosts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     *     public function getRoles()
     *     {
     *         return ['ROLE_USER'];
     *     }
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return string[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return ['ROLE_USER'];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see, at the top @ApiResource Annotations I am trying to have separate normalization and denormalization context for different groups.

When I test this by creating a user at `localhost:8000/api/users` with a POST request and the body as

```
{
    "username": "test_user1",
    "password": "TestUserPassword1",
    "email": "testUser1@email.com",
    "name": "Test User"
}
```

I receive this response

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
    "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "username: This value should not be blank.\npassword: This value should not be blank.\nname: This value should not be blank.\nemail: This value should not be blank.",
    "violations": [
        {
            "propertyPath": "username",
            "message": "This value should not be blank.",
            "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        },
        {
            "propertyPath": "password",
            "message": "This value should not be blank.",
            "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        },
        {
            "propertyPath": "name",
            "message": "This value should not be blank.",
            "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        },
        {
            "propertyPath": "email",
            "message": "This value should not be blank.",
            "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!!

I am using:

- PHP 7.4.3
- Symfony 5

My composer.json file:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^2.6",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.8",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^3.2",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.11",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.1",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/asset": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.14",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.30"
    }
}
```

Comment: In [the docs about operations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/) all examples operations names are lower case. Yours are upper case. Have you tried with lower case names?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that when sending a `POST` request to your server, you use the `Content-Type: application/json` header? Else Symfony will not properly decode your body payload.

Comment: Yes I do ensure that the content type is `application/json` the result is same!